# How to know current Renderable cameras in Maya using Mel command or python script

Tags: python, maya, mel

I want to know the information of Renderable Camera of layers using MEL command or python in MAYA.

**MEL code for Render layers:**

```
$layers = 'ls -type "renderLayer"';
```

This code gives me render layers but I want Renderable Camera too.Please help me

**Expected Output**

```
Layer           Camera

Defaultlayer    Layout_camera:masterCam
second_layer    Layout_camera:masterCam
```

I have got the Layer but i have stuck on the camera's part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code gives me render layers and camera .

```
$layers = `ls -type "renderLayer"`;

for( $layer in $layers )
   {    
     print($layer);
     print("\n");

     editRenderLayerGlobals -currentRenderLayer $layer;

     string $cameras[] = `ls -type camera`;

     for ($camera in $cameras)
     { 
        if (getAttr ($camera+".renderable"))
            print ($camera+"\n");
     }
}
```